# R Yield Curve package to extract term rates in days

Tags: r, quantitative-finance

I am using the Yield Curve package to estimate the term structure following the Nelson-Siegel (NS) method.

My approach follows first to estimate the NS model parameters, and subsequently use these estimated parameters to arrive at rates for the required set of maturities.

As stated in the Yield Curve documentation, the estimation of NS parameters requires two inputs - rates, and a vector of maturities corresponding to these rates. Importantly, the maturities are to be expressed in months.

In the next step, estimating the NS rates takes two inputs - NS parameters and a vector of maturities for which the interest rates are required. Unlike the previous step, the documentation corresponding to this step does not state how the maturities are to be expressed (days/months/years?). I am interested in estimating the interest rates for very short term maturities like 1,2,3,4,5 days.

I am hoping someone here could help elaborate on this.

Following is an excerpt from my code:

**Vector of maturities corresponding to the data contained in xts object rates. I divide by 30 to achieve the result that maturities are expressed in terms of months.**

```
    maturity <- c(1/30,7/30,14/30,1)
```

**Vector of maturities for which I want to get the interest rate.**

```
    term <- 1:12 /30
```

**Estimate the Nelson-Siegel model parameters**

```
    NSParameters <- Nelson.Siegel(rate = rate, maturity = maturity)
```

**Use the NS model parameters to estimate the interest rates for the required maturities.**

```
    NS_rates <- NSrates(NSParameters, term)
```

My output results don't seem to make much sense, which makes me wonder whether I am expressing the maturities in the required format.

PS. I have gone through all queries submitted on this forum pertaining to the Yield Curve package however I am so far unable to find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

the Nelson.Siegel parameters have to be in `xts` format.
Since you did not provide the rate vector I created one myself.

```
library(YieldCurve)
maturity <- c(1/30, 7/30, 14/30, 1)
rate <- c(-0.004217, -0.004248, -0.003909, -0.003819)
nsp <- xts(Nelson.Siegel(rate, maturity), order.by = as.Date("2019-10-12"))


term <- 1:12/30
as.numeric(NSrates(nsp, term))

 [1] -0.004288541 -0.004287670 -0.004286799 -0.004285930 -0.004285062 -0.004284195
 [7] -0.004283329 -0.004282463 -0.004281599 -0.004280736 -0.004279874 -0.004279013
```